# Is it possible to make the authorization header optional on an HTTP request?

Tags: api, rest, http, backend

So I am creating a forum website (like reddit). On a thread, I want to have two different ways of requesting the thread's comments from the backend.

- One for if a user is not logged in.
- One for if a user is logged in.

**With the request for when a user is not logged in**

I want to just return the comments with an:

- `upvoteCount` value (for how many users upvoted the comment)
- no `userUpvoted` value (or `userUpvoted = null`)

**With the request for when a user is logged in**

I want to return:

- `upvoteCount` value
- `userUpvoted` value (so the frontend can display if the user upvoted the comment)

The endpoint will be something like this:

```
GET /thread/{threadID}/comments?startIndex={start index}&count={number of comments to return}
```

For the user that is logged in, I will send the authorization token in the header.

For the user that is not logged in, I will not send the authorization token in the header.

Is it possible to make sending the authorization header optional to an HTTP request like this?

Or should I just make two separate endpoints?

Comment: Yes. That is normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make sending the authorization header optional to an HTTP request like this?  Or should I just make two separate endpoints?

Yes, you can vary the representation (content) of a resource based on whether or not the authorization field is present in the request.

Is it a good idea?  That's a harder question.

You already know how two separate resources works; there aren't going to be any significant surprises there.

We also have a standardized mechanism for indicating that multiple representations of a single resource are available.

But the Authorization field, specifically, is sort of a special case because of the role that field plays in access control; that has implications on how general purpose caches work, and therefore the Vary field that we use for indicating multiple representations has an exemption for the authorization field, etc....

---

If you submitted a single resource implementation like this for code review, I'd insist on a decision record as well, so that we have a permanent record of which trade offs we were considering (including, for instance, what's supposed to happen when Alice the Super Admin needs to verify the "anonymous" variation of the representation).